# Equivalent linux command of "net start" command in windows

Tags: windows, linux, windows-command-prompt

On Windows a command like `net start mysql` will try to start the MySQL service. I am looking for equivalent Linux command to do that - to change the status of services through Linux commands.

Comment: It depends somewhat on what distro you're using.  Many use the scripts in `/etc/rc.d`, but Ubuntu encourages you to use `service`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of linux'es support the service command

```
service mysql.server start
```

This is related to chkconfig

```
[root@iceweasel init.d]# chkconfig --list mysql.server

Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native
      systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native
      systemd configuration.

mysql.server    0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Otherwise you can do it the old fashioned way

```
cd /etc/init.d
./mysql.server start
```

Comment: init.d/rc.d depends on the distro.

Comment: @Andrew totally - can you remember/know some distro's that still use the /etc/rc.d style and I'll list them and I will add them to my answer with accreditation.

Answer (score 3):

Your "service" scripts are all stored in `/etc/init.d`, so the normal way is to use `sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start` (or whatever service you want to start). Modern Linux distributions have the `service` command which does a similar thing, so also try `service mysqld start`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Linux distros have an `rc` script; for example:

```
/etc/rc.d/apache2 restart | stop
/etc/rc.d/mysqld start | stop
```